# Multiple Picker views: Inconsistent, cycle drop down lists

Tags: swiftui, picker

I have a form with three different picker views. When I run the app and click on one of the pickers, the drop-down content is populated from another picker and it spontaneously cycles through the other two picker contents before returning to the main view. I am gogin to kick myself when someone points to something very fundamental and basic.... but here is the code . And thanks in advance!

```
var body: some View {
    Form{
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("PaO2")
                TextField("mmHg", text: $PaO2)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                Spacer()
                Text("O2(%)")
                TextField("%", text: $FiO2)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }
            Toggle("Mechnical Ventilation", isOn: $MV)
           
            HStack {
                Text("Platelets")
                TextField("(x1000)", text: $Platelets)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }
            
            Picker(selection: $GCSSelected, label: Text("Glasgow Coma Scale")) {
                ForEach(0..<GCS.count){ index1 in
                Text(self.GCS[index1]).tag(index1)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            Picker(selection: $HDSelected, label: Text("MAP/use of vasoactive Rx")){
                ForEach(0..<HD.count){ index2 in
                    Text(self.HD[index2]).tag(index2)
                }
            }
            HStack{
                Text("Bilirubin")
                TextField("mg/dL", text: $Bili)
                    .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
            }
            
            Picker(selection: $RenalSelected, label: Text("Creatinine or Urine output")){
                ForEach(0..<Renal.count){ index3 in
                    Text(self.Renal[index3]).tag(index3)
                }

            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to used single view for entire `Form` content, but you should not, so

```
var body: some View {
    Form{
        VStack {    // << remove this container and let every picker be in own row
```